# Got a blank white page after deploying react app to gitlab pages

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy my react app (not create-react-app, built from skratch) to gitlab pages, all jobs are passed successfully, but the page is not working correctly. I have just a blank white page.

my .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  image: node:latest    
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install   
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/          

pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none 
  script:
    - mv build public      
    - cd public 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

My **webpack**, I merge common with prod

webpack.common.js

```js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] 
    },
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.tsx'
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        publicPath: "/"
      },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].[contenthash].css', chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].css' }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html",
            inject: "body",
            minify: {
              minifyCSS: true,
              minifyJS: true,
              collapseWhitespace: true
            }
          }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|prod)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

webpack.prod.js

```js
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
             })],
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            name: 'runtime',
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    }
})
```

package.json

```json
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
    },
```

As I mentioned locally works fine, both dev server and build.

I have no console error, just a warning:

> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature:
> 'interest-cohort'.

and

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
> https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in with MIME type text/html. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
> details.

I logged out, when I logged in I get 401err

> GET https://projects.gitlab.io/auth?code=2.... net::ERR_ABORTED 401

project is public

Comment: check console error and edit here

Comment: no errors, a few warnings regarding authorization in gitlab, edited question

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Turned out  `homepage` attribute in `package.json`was containing incorrect site url.

You need to add this attribute (if not already) at the top of `package.json`, and make sure it is pointing to the gitlab pages url for your site.

```
{
   "homepage": "GITLAB_PAGES_URL",
   "name": "...",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to clarify the answer from Waleed93 as i just ran into the same issue.

Gitlab Pages use URLs of the following format for pages: `https://<username>.gitlab.com/<repository>`

The default setup for a react app is that the page lives at `/` and hence the manifest.js would be available at `/manifest.js`. But now the page is at `/<repository>`. So when trying to download `/manifest.js` we actually just hit a gitlab auth wall at `https://<username>.gitlab.com/manifest.js`. The solution is adding `"homepage": <repository>` to `package.json` or adding your own domain to your Gitlab page